# Allow non-admin users to access plug-in

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I want users who are not Administrator to be able to use my Calendar plugin, but it is not available on the dashboard except to Administrator.

Comment: Contact the plugin author or view the plugin's source and find out which capability(s) a user needs to use the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap)

```
function add_theme_caps(){
 global $pagenow;

 if ( 'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ){ // Test if theme is activated
  // Theme is activated
  // gets the author role
  $role = get_role( 'author' );

  // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
  // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
 }
 else {
  // Theme is deactivated
  // Remove the capacity when theme is deactivated
  $role->remove_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
 }
}
add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'add_theme_caps' );
```

with small edit to make author can install,edit and activate plugins

```
function add_theme_caps(){
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'themes.php' == $pagenow && isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ){ // Test if theme is activated
    // Theme is activated
    // gets the author role
    $role = get_role( 'author' );

    // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
    // would allow the author to edit others' posts for current theme only
    $role->add_cap( 'activate_plugins' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_plugins' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'install_plugins' ); 
}
else {
    // Theme is deactivated
    // Remove the capacity when theme is deactivated
    $role->remove_cap( 'edit_others_posts' ); 
}
}
add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'add_theme_caps' );
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to grant access to a particular plugin. Your code will allow authors to install, edit & activate *any* plugin - not ideal.